# Dart: BroadcastStream keeping last state?

Tags: dart, stream

I am connecting to a bluetooth device (ble) which sends me data. Since I only can have ONE connection, but I need the stream in several places (at the same time) I thought a broadcast stream would be a good solution for that.

Problem with broadcast is, that the items are not kept. (In general I think it's not a good approach, that the not-broadcast-stream keeps all the items emitted..., just seems wrong)

To get the required behaviour I am doing this:

```
StreamGroup.merge([
      Future.value(_latestItemEmitted).asStream(),
      broadcast.stream
    ])
    .where((item) => item != null) // to avoid emitting null in the initial state of the `_lastItemEmitted`
    .distinct() // to avoid duplicates
```

This is working but comes with a couple of downsides.

- I always have to store the last emitted item.
- It seems weird to group a stream for that case.

I don't want to use RxDart for this. (I am sure one of you guys have an easy solution for this case)

I am basically searching for a broadcast-stream wrapper to achieve this behaviour.

Comment: "I think it's not a good approach, that the not-broadcast-stream keeps all the items emitted" - it doesn't keep them forever, it buffers while there is no listener.

Answer (score 1):

https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject-class.html does that

A special StreamController that captures the latest item that has been added to the controller, and emits that as the first item to any new listener.

> This subject allows sending data, error and done events to the
>   listener. The latest item that has been added to the subject will be
>   sent to any new listeners of the subject. After that, any new events
>   will be appropriately sent to the listeners. It is possible to provide
>   a seed value that will be emitted if no items have been added to the
>   subject.
>
> BehaviorSubject is, by default, a broadcast (aka hot) controller, in
>   order to fulfill the Rx Subject contract. This means the Subject's
>   `stream` can be listened to multiple times.

Comment: As I've been writing I am searching for a solution without RxDart

Comment: Then copy the implementation ;-) I don't think there anything else that would be better than rxdart. Any reason why you try to avoid rxdart?

Comment: I just don't want to pull the whole library for that single function. Additionally RxDart seems (compared to rxjava2) still a bit retarded.

Comment: "a bit retarded" that's probably because of current Dart limitations. "on't want to pull the whole library" Dart only imports files, not whole packages and tree-shaking removes unused code anyway. I think you are giving up a lot of potential for little benefit.

Comment: You convinced me to use rxdart. Then it was super easy. But instead of a BehaviourSubject I've been using the `shareReplay` operator, since my stream is a "broadcast" one.

Comment: Sounds great. It also does not drag in a single dependency, so it's really very lightweight.